# Unity ,ios and Hybrid Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, hybrid

[image]

I have a hybrid app which has a game to play in that and integrated that game using iOS native components.When the user clicks on a button in Hybrid it calls a native method called `GameInvoke` ,From there I'm adding unity view as subview and presenting the Native ViewController.It works fine till here.

When the user clicks on exit button in the Game.It is calling a method called `UnityRequestQuit()` which is in the `UnityAppcontroller`.

I am dismissing the viewcontroller which I presented earlier to invoke the game in the `UnityRequestQuit()`.When I did that it is crashing the application.

Comment: Post the stacktrace and include the exception text.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry for the delay in response. Debugging the issue and couldn't find where the bug lies.Updated with the exception please check